# How can I install Gnome2 on recent versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome, software-installation

How can I install Gnome 2 on Ubuntu 13.10 - Server X86-64? I'm aware this is not an easy question given many of the dependencies of Gnome 2 have been upgraded in 13.10 and therefore cause a problem, I discovered this when I tried using the 10.10 repos with my 13.10 install. Please don't suggest alternatives, I'm aware of them.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to install GNOME 2. Gnome 2 depends heavily on GTK+2 which it's being depreciated in later versions of Ubuntu. If you somehow manage to "install" GNOME 2 you will get an unstable system. The only way is to get some fork of GNOME like MATE or Cinnamon. Otherwise, no.